# Diffrence between output of elastic nested boolean queries

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, booleanquery

I would like to know if the following two elastic queries would lead to difrent outcomes or same?

```html
{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"assignee.raw":["AHMEDABAD TEXTILE INDUSTRY'S RESEARCH ASSOCIATION","AHMEDABAD TEXTILE INDUSTRY'S RESERCH ASSOCIATION","AHMEDABAD TEXTILE INDUSTRY?S RESEARCH ASSOCIATION"]}},{"query_string":{"query":"(UNDER EXTENSION ) OR ( INFORCE)","default_operator":"AND","default_field":"legalStatusText"}}]}},{"terms":{"agent.agency.raw":["EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PVT. LTD.","EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED","EPIPHANY IP SOLUTIONS PVT. LTD"]}}]}}
```

**AND..........**

```html
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "assignee.raw": [
                        "SANJAY BAJAJ",
                        "GTG GMBH"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "agent.agency.raw": [
                        "JK STEEL",
                        "ANAND AND ANAND"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "(EXPIRED) OR (APPLICATION WITHDRAWN)",
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "default_field": "legalStatusText"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically Does The Extra ***bool:must*** in the second snippet makes any difference in the output?

Answer (score 0):

The first query would be `(A AND B) OR C`

The second query would be `((A AND B) AND C) OR true`

So the first and second queries are **NOT equivalent** because the difference is not about the extra `bool/must`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what does 'OR TRUE' mean?

Comment: I added `OR true` just because in the second query you only have a single constraint in `bool/should` so there's basically no OR